# How to show object property with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

OK. Here we go. I'm trying to build simple app with MEAN. And when I show my object with angular `{{object}}` it prints the object on my page but when I try to print object property `{{object.property}}` nothing happens.

Below is the relevant part of the code. How do you print property of the object?

**Mongo**

```
> db.myapp.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564983745dc4b169cba8c9fc"),
    "type" : "balance",
    "value" : "111"
}
```

**Server code**

```
app.get('/myapp', function (req,res) {
    db.myapp.find(function(err,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
$http.get('/myapp').success(function (response) {
        $scope.balance = response;
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<p>{{balance}}</p>
<p>{{balance.type}}</p>
<p>{{balance.value}}</p>
```

Result with the above HTML is following.

```
[{"_id":"564983745dc4b169cba8c9fc","type":"balance","value":"111"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the JSON shows, balance is not an object. It's an array, containing a single element, which is an object. So you would need

```
{{ balance[0].type }}
```

to print the type.

If the REST service is supposed to return a single object, then fix it. If it's indeed supposed to return several ones, then the view should have a loop to display all the elements:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in balance">
    {{ item.type }}
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. Does it come out as array from mongo or where does that happen?

Comment: I don't know MongoDB very much, and node even less, but I'd guess that a call to `db.myapp.find()` would indeed retrieve all the elements of the myapp collection, and thus return an array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your response object is an array (that's why it's rendered in square brackets).

In that case use `$scope.balance = response[0]` in your controller or `{{balance[0].type}}` in the markup.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Does it come out as array from mongo or where does that happen?

Comment: @Kaimaan: I don't know mongo, but with a quick search I found: `find()` returns a collection, while `findOne()` returns the first matching record. See here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<section class="content row" ng-repeat="item in data">
    Name: {{item.name}} <br/>
    BaseValue: <input type="text" ng-init="item.oldBaseValue = item.baseValue" ng-model="item.baseValue" ng-change="baseValueChange(item.oldBaseValue, item.baseValue); item.oldBaseValue = item.baseValue"/>
</section>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.baseValueChange = function(oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log("base value change", oldVal, newVal);
}
```